# Convergence of series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that if the sequence  is bounded, and the series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ also converges absolutely.

Conclude that the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})S_n$$
which $S_n=\sum sen kx$ converges

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partial sums
$$\left|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p} {a_n b_n} \right| \leqslant \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p} \left|{a_n b_n} \right|= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{p} {\left(\left|a_n\right| \cdot\left| b_n\right|\right)} \leqslant B\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p} {\left|a_n\right| }.$$

Answer (score 0):

(Since it's homework, this is not a complete solution.)

If $(b_n)$ is bounded, then there is a number $M$ such that $|b_n| \le M$ for all $n$. Compare $\sum a_n b_n$ with a known absolutely convergent series to conclude that it converges absolutely.

For the second part, write $\sin kx = \operatorname{Im} e^{ikx}$ and use a geometric sum to show that $(S_n)$ is bounded. (Note that your series should start with $n=1$.)